# Z-index and wmode not working with YouTube embed code in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, wmode

I'm trying to create a div that will cover an iframe containing YouTube embed code, so when the user clicks on the video, javascript will fire *instead* of playing the video. I have included the wmode=opaque parameter in the src attribute, as every Google search tells you to do. This is currently working in Chrome and Firefox, but it does not work in IE10.

Below is what I currently have.

```
<div class="cover" onclick="alert('Working');" style="height: 350px; width: 350px;"></div>
<iframe width="350" height="350" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/18YA73npI6s?wmode=opaque">
```

And CSS

```
div.cover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
iframe {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Above code live: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azXe6/1/).

Any insight into why this isn't working in IE10 would be helpful.

Comment: Its like rocket science when you are working around IE

Answer (score 0):

this was the only way i could manage

http://jsfiddle.net/azXe6/2/

```
div.cover {
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
background-color:red;  /* added this*/
opacity:0; /* added this*/
}
```